# Nodejs invalid input syntax for integer error

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express

I using postgres sql, nodejs, express

```
     app.get("/topic/create", function(req, res) {
      var sql = "SELECT id, title FROM topic";
      client.query(sql, function(err, res2) {
        console.log(res2.rows);
        //res.render("create", { topics: res2.rows });
      });
    });
```

this code is my router code 
but when i enter that url it was error

> ```
>    error: invalid input syntax for integer: "create"
>   name: 'error',
>   length: 110,
>   severity: 'ERROR',
>   code: '22P02',  line: '62',routine: 'pg_atoi'
> ```

i dont know reason because sql was working on other url only that app.get code doesn't working

```
    //라우팅 작업
    app.get("/", function(req, res) {
      res.redirect("/topic");
    });
    app.get("/topic", function(req, res) {
      var sql = "SELECT id, title FROM topic";
      client.query(sql, function(err, res2) {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
        } else {
          res.render("view", { topics: res2.rows });
        }
      });
    });
app.get("/topic/:id", function(req, res) {
  var id = req.params.id;
  var sql1 = "SELECT id, title FROM topic";
  var sql2 = "SELECT * FROM topic where id=$1";
  client.query(sql2, [id], function(err, res2) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      client.query(sql1, function(err, res3) {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
          res.status(500).send("Internal Server Error");
        } else {
          var list = [];
          var result = res3.rows;
          for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
            list.push(res3.rows[i]);
          }
          res.render("view", { details: res2.rows, topics: list });
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
```

this is my router code it was same. this code is good working

i dont know why only that url make error

Comment: Did you define your `/topic/create` route before something like `/topic/:id`?

Comment: yes i made /topic/:id

Comment: @tadman i add /topic/:id code in my question

Comment: whats `$1`, have you defined it purposely

Comment: $1 is id it is my db id i can get that using  req.params.id;

Comment: @ArunK i push that id in html 
~~~
each topic in topics 
              li
                a(href='/topic/'+topic.id)= topic.title
~~~
like this

Comment: whats the current error you get

Comment: this is my error @ArunK error: invalid input syntax for integer: "create"

Comment: see my answer, when you define the functions, which one did you define first. `/topic/create` or `/topic/:id`. thats what @tadman meant as well, right ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
app.get("/topic/create", function(req, res) {
      var sql = "SELECT id, title FROM topic";
      client.query(sql, function(err, res2) {
        console.log(res2.rows);
        //res.render("create", { topics: res2.rows });
      });
    });
```

You have to put this router first then below one,

```
app.get("/topic/:id", function(req, res) {
  var id = req.params.id;
  var sql1 = "SELECT id, title FROM topic";
  var sql2 = "SELECT * FROM topic where id=$1";
  client.query(sql2, [id], function(err, res2) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      client.query(sql1, function(err, res3) {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
          res.status(500).send("Internal Server Error");
        } else {
          var list = [];
          var result = res3.rows;
          for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
            list.push(res3.rows[i]);
          }
          res.render("view", { details: res2.rows, topics: list });
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
```

this will work, Because express take and match with first one. It get failed, That's why you got this error.

Comment: I was perfectly working. thanks a lot.
I didn't know express was important about function order

Answer (score 3):

as @tadman mentioned, you need to define `app.get("/topic/create` function before the `app.get("/topic/:id"` function. otherwise, express thinks that you are executing `app.get("/topic/:id"` and the id is `create`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank u for yout help. 
I didn't know function order was important in express

Comment: Glad to be of help.